# Why my addon does not show up in user preferences?

Tags: python, add-on

I am very new to Blender add-on development and having some trouble getting mine to actually show up and or enable

[image: ScreenShot_addon install_ non listed]

I want it to show-up here:

[image: desired addon-location]

```
import os
import bpy
bl_info = {
    "name" : "CudaParticals",
    "author" : "Max Oltersdorf",
    "description" : "Enables the use of NIVIDA CUDA for Large realistic Particle Simulations",
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "location" : "Properties", # This is a new tab in the "properties section"
    "warning" : "IN EARLY DEVELOPMENT",
    "category" : "SYSTEM"
    #"wiki_url": "'https://github.com/OltersdorfTechnology/CudaParticals/wiki'",
    #"tracker_url": "https://github.com/OltersdorfTechnology/CudaParticals/issues",
    "support": "Testing",
}
from bpy.types import (
    Operator,
    Panel,
    PropertyGroup,
)
from bpy.props import (
    BoolProperty,
    EnumProperty,
    Pointe
# Define the interface
class CudaParticlePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "CudaParticle_Panel"
    bl_label = "CudaParticle"
    bl_category = "SYSTEM"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
   # bl_context = "CudaParticle"

    def draw(self, context):    
        layout = self.layout

        #scene = context.scene

        layout.label(text= "CudaParticals Properties:")

        #row = layout.row()
        #row.operator("view3d.print_text", text = "Print text", icon='WORLD_DATA')
        global custom_icons
        self.layout.label(text="CudaParticle",
# end define interface
icon_value=custom_icons["custom_icon"].icon_id)
# global variable to store icons in
custom_icons = None
classes = (
    CudaParticlePanel,
)
def register():
    global custom_icons
    custom_icons = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    script_path = bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath
    icons_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(script_path), "Icons")
    custom_icons.load("Tool_Icon", os.path.join(icons_dir, "Tool_Icon.png"), 'IMAGE')
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
def unregister():
    global custom_icons
    bpy.utils.previews.remove(custom_icons)
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in classes:
        unregister_class(cls)
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in the imports, a closing bracket is missing. The class "Pointe" doesn't exist, as far as I'm aware. The level of indentation for the arguments of `self.layout.label(text="CudaParticle, ...` looks incorrect on my phone. Check the console for error messages. The biggest problem is that you cannot add your own property tabs, to the best of my knowledge. You can add your own panels in an existing one though.

Comment: Thanks @RobertGützkow for the help.
always good to have a second pair of eyes look things over..

"The biggest problem is that you cannot add your own property tabs, to the best of my knowledge. You can add your own panels in an existing one though." 
I'll take this into consideration... maybe i need to make my own version of blender...